# Is there a way to remove big blue bar on top of google documents after running a script using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a google apps script for a private reason but this is nothing about the code. If you are confused by the title, I will explain what I mean:
I'm pretty sure most google drive users have used add-ons before. When you launch an addon, it runs a script. Perfectly normal, but the thing is, you don't know when it is running a script because there isn't anything indicating it. What I want is to hide that big blue bar that appears when you run a script.

I tried looking at Google Apps Script's website but if you tried searching something like this on the web, your browser won't understand you which is why I decided to use stack overflow.

Here is a picture of what I want to get rid of:

[image: Stuff]

as you can see here the I want to hide the "Finished Script" thing using Google Apps Script or some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [blog](https://www.pr2020.com/blog/how-to-build-your-own-powerful-marketing-performance-tools), as soon as you click the Apps Script button, you’ll see a yellow bar "`Running function <function-name>`". This will indicate that the script is running. When done, the bar will read “**Finished Script**”. This is a built-in Google Apps Script feature. I think you will not be able to remove this feature.

Comment: I don't think so because add-ons are made using google apps script but they don't show that blue bar.